# Fully dealloc NSMutableDictionary / NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-management, nsdictionary

I am retrieving a tremendous amount of data from a server and I have to quickly initialize and deallocate a `NSMutableDictionary`.

I would use core data but requirements say I have to use one allocated object for fast storage of incoming `JSON` data, save it to `NSUserDefaults` and completely remove it. This will be happening multiple times in a background process over a period of time.

Tests were on a live iPhone 6S (not a simulator)

I tested a completely bare "Single View Application" that resulted with:

[image: First Test]

As you can see a bare bones "Single View Application" consumes 9MB of memory.

I then ran a test on a `NSMutableDictionary`. My test was to initialize with data, remove all objects, and restore the RAM.

The dictionary stored 10,000 tiny values (in `viewDidLoad` - for testing purposes):

```
_dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:@{
                      @"Item00000" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                      ...
                      @"Item10000" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:10000]}];
```

After initializing - I waited two seconds and removed all objects and attempted to remove the `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_largeDictionary removeAllObjects];
    _largeDictionary = nil;
});
```

But the memory consumption did *not* show the `NSMutableDictionary` getting removed:

[image: Second Test]

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I thought this was taken care of when Apple depreciated the `autorelease` method. My live environment is quickly initializing relatively large chunks of data *per* key-value pair - then deallocating and preparing for the next chunk. The next chunk ***may*** be stored in a different `NSMutableDictionary`. That's why it is necessary for me to completely remove the first `NSMutableDictionary` from memory. I have seen many answers pertaining to this question but none more recent than 2013.

**Update:** this `@property` is: `(nonatomic, strong)`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to enclose your code with a@autoreleasepool { /* code that creates/destroys dict */}.  You are creating lot of autoreleased objects out there.

Comment: 9MB or 10MB is not enough memory to be worrying about. If there's a real problem, use Instruments, not that silly gauge thing in Xcode, to see what's going with memory.

Comment: Agreed, but this was a unit test to check the code. See if it was actually removing it completely. This is going to be used for mega sized dictionaries with up to 4kb objects. We limit it at 4kb `JSON` for a value. But we can have 10k-1M objects coming in, storing, rendering, or being used some how - meanwhile the next request gets fired and put into the dictionary. We tested this with the full scale data and it resulted in about 400-600MB overhead we did not calculate. So I scaled down the data to check each piece. This 1MB difference appears to represent the dictionary on the stack

Comment: Yes this seems a bit ridiculous but it is being used for enterprise application. Not App Store. The purpose is to have a "host" iPad ad hoc feed data to other devices in the same wifi. Data being fed may vary. This is simply a test with a weird result. @matt I will try instruments more in depth and I'll try that autoreleasepool scope, thank you!